# How to restrict captured video size(20MB to 30MB) in titanium?

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have a requirement that need to take video and upload to server. In server we have upload limit as 20MB to 30MB so my video size should not exceed that limit.

Is that possible to handle video size or video seconds 60 to 120 seconds. It should work in all type of devices like ipad,iPhone6 and iphone6plus same like android higher resolution devices too.

Whats the best approach to handle this requirement. 
1) Video size restriction.
2) Video capturing seconds restriction.
3) Video edit cropping video to match the size.

Please suggest me any idea or approach.

Answer (score 2):

There is the videoMaximumDuration property on the [CameraOptionsType](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/CameraOptionsType) Object.

```js
Ti.Media.showCamera({
  videoMaximumDuration: 20
});
```

Restricting by the video filesize is not possible when capturing. You would have to set the videoMaximumDuration dynamically according to the capturing device - but thats not accurate.

If you just want to bypass the upload restriction you could chunk the upload of the videofile like so: http://lowb1rd.github.io/002-chunked-uploads-with-titanium.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will try chunk upload.